# Difficulty creating a link to a stored file in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Trying to set up a table that contains links to files stored in a MySQL table. This is the code I wrote. It's the first time I've tried it with PDO, so I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
if(isset($_GET['ProposalNo']) && isset($_GET['UID'])) 
  {
   $fileget = $con->prepare("SELECT name, type, size, content FROM upload WHERE
   ProposalNo = :proposalno AND UID = :uid");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   $data = array('proposalno'=>$_GET['ProposalNo'],'uid'=>$_GET['UID']);
   $fileget->execute($data);
   list($name, $type, $size, $content) = $fileget->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   header("Content-length: $size");
   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   echo $content;

   exit;
  }
```

And here is the code that sets up the table:

```
$files = $con->prepare("SELECT UID, ProposalNo, name FROM upload");
$files->execute();
while($row = $files->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
   $uid = $row['UID'];
   $ProposalNo = $row['ProposalNo'];
   $Name = $row['name'];
 ?> 
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo "{$ProposalNo}</td>
 <td><a href=gcaforms.php?ProposalNo={$ProposalNo}&UID={$uid}>{$Name}</a></td>";?>

 </tr>
 <?php }?>
```

When I roll over the links created, the ProposalNo and UID show up correctly, but when I click on them, they only want me to open or save the referring page (gcaforms.php). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Changed $fileget->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to $fileget->(PDO::FETCH_BOTH).